# Passing down values from multiple Observables

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In my Angular service i have the following methods:

```
// creates an Item and returns the ID of the created Item
createItem(item: Item): Observable<ItemId> {
    return this.http.post<ItemId>('some_api_url', item);
}

// returns all Items
getAllItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.http.get<Item[]>('some_api_url');
}
```

In my template i'm showing the items in a list.

I would like to be able to create a new item and then re-load the list (to include the newly created item), so i've implemented the following:

```
this.itemService.createItem(item)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(createdId => this.itemService.getAllItems())
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result;
    });
```

This seemingly works fine, but in the end i would like to do some processing with the `createdId` as well:

```
this.itemService.createItem(item)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(createdId => this.itemService.getAllItems())
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result;

      // i would like to use createdId here as well
    });
```

So i've came up with the following:

```
this.itemService.createItem(item)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(createdId =>
         combineLatest(this.itemService.getAllItems(), of(createdId)))
    ).subscribe(result => {
      this.items = result[0];

      // doing some stuff with result[1], which is the value of createdId
    });
```

But having to use `combineLatest` inside the `switchMap` and explicitly make `createdId` an `Observable` makes me wonder if this is a good solution.

So basically i would like to create and item, update the list (when the item creation is finished) and use the ID of the created item when the update is finished.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'd really appreciate any advice.

Comment: I recommend changing this a bit and returning a subject, or better yet a behavior subject. That way you call next value of the service observable and return the subject as an observable. Any subscribers will get the new variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more digging into RxJS operators i figured the cleanest solution might be to simply combine `concat` with `toArray`:

```
// import { concat } from 'rxjs';
// import { toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

concat(
  this.itemService.createItem(item),
  this.itemService.getAllItems())
    .pipe(toArray())
    .subscribe((result: [ItemId, Item[]]) => {
      // result[0] is the ItemId
      // result[1] is the Item[]
    });
```

Comment: Im pretty sure that `toArray` is not requried

Comment: @Jota.Toledo As i understand, without the `toArray` this would result in emitting two separate values, first the `ItemId` and then the `Item[]`. I need them both and only when both of them completes, so it is required i think.

Comment: Indeed, oversaw that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `concatMap` operator. 
Try to first create the item, then wait for the execution using the `concatMap` operator. Take the output of the execution in the `allItems` observable and then merge the results using a `map` operator. In the subscribe, you will have an object of `createdItem` and `allItems`

```
const createdItem = this.itemService.createItem(item);
const allItems = this.itemService.getAllItems();

createdItem
  .pipe(
    concatMap(item =>
              allItems.pipe(
                map(items => ({
                  createdItem: item,
                  items
                })
              )
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pipe the result of the inner observable in order to further pass down the value emited by the source. You can do this as follows:

```
// I use a function here for the purpose of making the code more readable
const itemsWithNew = (newItemId) => this.itemService.getAllItems()
                                        .pipe(map(items => ({items,newItemId})));
this.itemService.createItem(item)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(itemsWithNew)
    ).subscribe(({items, newItemId})=> {
      this.items = items;

      // newItemId is the new value
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, `switchmap` also accepts a second result callback for processing both the outer value and inner value together.

```
this.itemService.createItem(item).pipe(
      switchMap(
        () => this.itemService.getAllItems(),
        (createdId, items) => {
           // can do some stuff here with both outer and inner values
           return { createdId, items };
        },
      ),
    ).subscribe({ createdId, allItems }) => {
      this.items = allItems;
    });
```

Comment: The selector function parameter is deprecated

Answer (score -1):

```
      // in your service 

        items: Item[]=[];
        $$items=new BehaviorSubject(this.items);


           // creates an Item and returns the ID of the created Item
            createItem(item: Item): Observable<ItemId> {
             return this.http.post<ItemId>('some_api_url', item)
           }

            // returns all Items
      getAllItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
     return this.http.get<Item[]>('some_api_url').pipe(map(response=>{
      return {//format response here//}

}).subscribe(result=>{
this.items=result;
     this.$$items.next(this.items);
        })
       }

       returnItemsAsObs(){
        return this.$$items.asObservable();

        }

         //in your component
          items:Item[]
            $$items: Subscription

         ngOninit(){
         this.service.getAllItems()
         this.$items=this.service.returnItemsAsObs().subscribe(items=>{
         this.items=items;
         return this.items;

      })


    onCreateItem(item){
    return this.service.createItem(item).subscribe(item=>{
    if(item.length<0){
    //call other service for itemid manipulation
    this.service.getAllItems();


     }

    })


    }


    }
```